# Visual Studio 2012 crashes when selecting Tools | Options

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ide

I've installed **Visual Studio 2012 Professional** and applied **Update 4**.

Every time I choose **Tools | Options**, it crashes. This is **with and without** the Update.

I checked online, but can't find anything concrete to solve the issue.

Below, is the output when it crashes.

**Could somebody please help?** I really need to set up the environment the way I need it.

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: devenv.exe
  Application Version:  11.0.50727.1
  Application Timestamp:    5011ecaa
  Fault Module Name:    msenv.dll
  Fault Module Version: 11.0.50727.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   5011ecbd
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 00241a7d
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Locale ID:    1033
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

### Edit - Additonal Info in the Event Log

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsUIDataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.Internal.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.DataSource.Invoke(System.String, System.Object, System.Object ByRef)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.VsCommand.Execute(System.Object)
   at MS.Internal.Commands.CommandHelpers.CriticalExecuteCommandSource(System.Windows.Input.ICommandSource, Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr, Boolean ByRef)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(System.Object)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(System.Object, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32, System.Delegate)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority, System.TimeSpan, System.Delegate, System.Object, Int32)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)


Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
Faulting module name: msenv.dll, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a98a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00244465
Faulting process id: 0x1420
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf325bc3504409
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll
Report Id: 0b1846b3-9e4f-11e3-969d-c4d9872304af


Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 34A64465
Stack:


Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a974
Faulting module name: msenv.dll, version: 11.0.61030.0, time stamp: 0x5270a98a
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00244465
Faulting process id: 0x1620
Faulting application start time: 0x01cf3262184216c6
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\msenv.dll
Report Id: 574d0df0-9e55-11e3-969d-c4d9872304af
```

Comment: Is there more information in the Event Viewer log?  Also, do you have any plugins?  Did it ever work?

Comment: I just posted the additional info from the event log. I have no plugins as of yet... I am running it on a 64 bit machine.

Comment: Now, I can't even open up any projects or C# files. What's going on????

Comment: The last two error sections were taken when simply trying to read in a C# file...

Comment: Did this ever work properly on that computer?  If so, when was the last time it worked properly?

Comment: Yes, when it was a 32 bit OS. It is now 64 bit. I downloaded and installed VS 2013 Pro with absolutely no issues whatsoever...

Comment: When you did the OS upgrade, did you re-install Visual Studio?